# How to retreive original folder contents from Appium pull_folder output?

Tags: base64, appium, zip, appium-android, python-appium

Based on the appium doc at http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/device/files/pull-folder/ a folder can be pulled following way

```
folder_base64 = self.driver.pull_folder('/path/to/device/foo.bar')
```

As per the doc the response folder_base64 is : **"A string of Base64 encoded data, representing a zip archive of the contents of the requested folder."**

So, based on my understanding of the above, i tried followings(A to D) which did not work.

**A)**

1. base64 decoding of the folder_base64
2. Unzipping the decoded output

`decoded_base64 = base64.b64decode(folder_base64)`

`folder_base64 = ZipFile.extractall(decoded_base64)`

this fails with following error:

```
zipfile.py", line 1493, in extractall
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'namelist'
```

**B)**

1. base64 decoding of the folder_base64
2. zipping the decoded output
3. unzipping

`decoded_base64 = base64.b64decode(folder_base64)
zipfile.ZipFile('out.zip', mode='w').write(decoded_base64)`

fails with following error at step 2:

```
zipfile.py", line 484, in from_file
    st = os.stat(filename)
ValueError: stat: embedded null character in path
```

**C)**

1. unzipping the folder_base64
2. base64 decoding of the output

`unzipped_base64 = ZipFile.extractall(folder_base64)
decoded_base64 = base64.b64decode(unzipped_base64)`

fails at step 1 with following error

```
zipfile.py", line 1493, in extractall
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'namelist'
```

**D)**

1. base64 decoding of the folder_base64
2. read the file as zip file
3. extract the files

`decoded_base64 = base64.b64decode(folder_base64)
zip_folder = zipfile.ZipFile(decoded_base64, 'r')
ZipFile.extractall(zip_folder, "./mp3_files")`

fails with following error:

```
zipfile.py", line 241, in _EndRecData
    fpin.seek(0, 2)
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'seek'
```

**E)**

**Finally following worked**, but i am wondering why it had to be routed via a temp file to make it work? Also, is there a better way/more direct way to handle appium pull_folder output?

```
decoded_base64 = base64.b64decode(folder_base64)
with SpooledTemporaryFile() as tmp:
    tmp.write(decoded_base64)
    archive = ZipFile(tmp, 'r')
    ZipFile.extractall(archive, "./mp3_files")
```

Note: following python packages are used in above code snippets

```
import zipfile
from tempfile import SpooledTemporaryFile
```

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this out of curiosity?

Comment: Went ahead with solution mentioned under E, but did not find answer to the question on why:)

Comment: Gettingg error SpooledTemporaryFile' object has no attribute 'seekable

Answer (score 0):

Also got error "SpooledTemporaryFile object has no attribute 'seekable'" from your solution E.

But this works for me:

```
folder_base64 = self.driver.pull_folder('/path/to/device/foo.bar')
decoded_base64 = base64.b64decode(folder_base64)

# write decoded content into a new file
with open("./archive.zip", "wb") as archive_file:
    archive_file.write(decoded_base64)

# extract created archive
with ZipFile('./archive.zip', 'r') as archive_file:        
    archive_file.extractall("./extracted_files")

# remove original file so only extracted files remain
os.remove("./archive.zip")
```